# spark-cassandra java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/japi/CassandraJavaUtil

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

```
16/04/26 16:58:46 DEBUG ProtobufRpcEngine: Call: complete took 3ms
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/japi/CassandraJavaUtil
        at com.baitic.mcava.lecturahdfssaveincassandra.TratamientoCSV.main(TratamientoCSV.java:123)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 10 more
16/04/26 16:58:46 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/04/26 16:58:46 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.128.0.5:4040
16/04/26 16:58:46 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
16/04/26 16:58:46 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
16/04/26 16:58:46 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/04/26 16:58:46 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/04/26 16:58:46 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/04/26 16:58:46 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/04/26 16:58:46 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/04/26 16:58:46 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
16/04/26 16:58:46 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
16/04/26 16:58:46 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/04/26 16:58:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/04/26 16:58:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /srv/spark/tmp/spark-2bf57fa2-a2d5-4f8a-980c-994e56b61c44
16/04/26 16:58:46 DEBUG Client: stopping client from cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@3fb9a67f
16/04/26 16:58:46 DEBUG Client: removing client from cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@3fb9a67f
16/04/26 16:58:46 DEBUG Client: stopping actual client because no more references remain: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@3fb9a67f
16/04/26 16:58:46 DEBUG Client: Stopping client
16/04/26 16:58:46 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (2107841088) connection to mcava-master/10.128.0.5:54310 from baiticpruebas2: closed
16/04/26 16:58:46 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (2107841088) connection to mcava-master/10.128.0.5:54310 from baiticpruebas2: stopped, remaining connections 0
16/04/26 16:58:46 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remoting shut down.
```

i make this simple code:

```
/  String pathDatosTratados="hdfs://mcava-master:54310/srv/hadoop/data/spark/DatosApp/medidasSensorTratadas.txt";
    String jarPath ="hdfs://mcava-master:54310/srv/hadoop/data/spark/original-LecturaHDFSsaveInCassandra-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar";
     String jar="hdfs://mcava-master:54310/srv/hadoop/data/spark/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.6.0-M1-4-g6f01cfe.jar";
    String jar2="hdfs://mcava-master:54310/srv/hadoop/data/spark/spark-cassandra-connector-java-assembly-1.6.0-M1-4-g6f01cfe.jar";
     String[] jars= new String[3];
     jars[0]=jarPath;
   jars[2]=jar;
     jars[1]=jar2;

    SparkConf conf=new SparkConf().setAppName("TratamientoCSV").setJars(jars);
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "10.128.0.5");
     conf.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max","512");
     conf.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer","256");
 //     conf.setJars(jars);
    JavaSparkContext sc= new  JavaSparkContext(conf);

     JavaRDD<String> input= sc.textFile(pathDatos);
```

i also put the path to cassandra drive in spark-default.conf

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath      hdfs://mcava-master:54310/srv/hadoop/data/spark/spark-cassandra-connector-java-assembly-1.6.0-M1-4-g6f01cfe.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath    hdfs://mcava-master:54310/srv/hadoop/data/spark/spark-cassandra-connector-java-assembly-1.6.0-M1-4-g6f01cfe.jar
```

i also put the flag --jars to the path of driver but i have always the same error i do not understand why??

i work in google engine

Answer (score 8):

Try to add package when you submit your app.

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.0-M2-s_2.11 ....
```

Comment: which scala version do you use? is it 2.11?

Comment: no the conector is 2.10...i use the last release of spark 1.6.1

Comment: then i asambly with sbt the conector i only find the .jar in scala 2.10 version, therefore, i cant find the java-assembly connector but when i search for CassandraUtils  i find the class in the scala asambly...i dont know how i can solve the problem..when i worked in my local computer all work perfect but in the google engine i cant solve this problem..dont have any sense for me it

Comment: maybe you can use  --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.0-M2-s_2.10 then?

Comment: i try with it but i have a problem with serialization version  but i try with --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.0-M1-s_2.10 and it runs ok but when ithe app achieve the code  to save data in cassandra the same error output...i do not have idea why jvm dont find the class CassandraUtils i cant resolve the problem..it is so frustrating

Answer (score 2):

I add this argument to solve this problem:  --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.0-M2-s_2.10.

Answer (score 1):

At least for 3.0+ spark cassandra connector, [the official assembly jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12) works well for me. It has all the necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem... i maked a fat jar with all dependencies and it not necessary to indicate the references to the cassandra connector only the reference to the fat jar.

Answer (score 0):

I used Spark in my Java programm, and had the same issue. 
The problem was, because I didn`t include *spark-cassandra-connector* into my maven dependencies of my project.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7</version> <!-- Check actual version in maven repo -->
    </dependency>
```

After that I builld **fat jar** with all my dependencies - and it`s worked! 
Maybe it will help someone